# Showing specific value from ajax return data

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I am sending data using jquery ajax as follow to a servlet

```
   var dataString = 'messageid='+ msgid1+'&receivedById='+receiverid; 
    $.ajax({   
    type: "POST",   
    url: "fetchSharePage", 
    dataType: "text html",
    data: dataString,   
    success: function(data) { 

           $(".sharePost").html(data);

    }   
    });
```

Here it is showing all data as `data` to `<div class="sharePost">`.

Here I want to show only
variable 
`status`  and `addActionMessage("Done this");` value in `<div class="sharePost">`
containd in `data`

Comment: @Sushanth the dataType is not JSON. Are you just returning an HTML doc?

Comment: Status is variable defined in Servlet

Comment: Best thing to do would be to change your servlet to return JSON instead of html.

Comment: You could return JSP as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You would do well to change to JSON, then it's simple to just to the following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "yourUrl" ,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: showItems
      });

function showItems(request, status, error) {
      $('.sharePost').append(status + ': ' + error + ' ' + request + '<br>');
    }
```

(this is excerpted from my showerror code, but just try using a function where one of the parameters are named 'status')  :)